# select de html me lo pone dos veces en pantalla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

cuando escribo un select de htlm me lo pone normal en pantalla, pero cuando lo hago multiselect con jquery me lo duplica

HTML
este es el codigo del html

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="SelectdestinoP" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Destino del paquete</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
              <select id="SelectdestinoP" name="SelectdestinoP">
                <option value=""> < Selecciona > </option>
                <option value="">Dpto Adquisiciones</option>
                <option value="">Dpto Capital Humano</option>
                <option value="">Dpto Sistemas</option>
                <option value="">Dpto Finanzas</option>
                <option value="">Dpto Cobranza</option>
                <option value="">Dpto Auditoria Interna</option>
                <option value="">Dpto Educacion</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectDestinatario" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Destinatario</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
              <select id="selectDestinatario" name="selectDestinatario">
                <option value=""> < Selecciona > </option>
                <option value="">Alejandro Calixto</option>
                <option value="">Antonio Solis Aleman</option>
                <option value="">Jose Luis Hernandez</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="selectIpoPaquete" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tipo de paquete</label>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
              <select id="selectIpoPaquete" name="selectIpoPaquete">
                <option value=""> < Selecciona > </option>
                <option value="">Sobres</option>
                <option value="">Cajas</option>
                <option value="">Folletos</option>
                <option value="">Bolsas</option>
                <option value="">Polizas</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

JS
y con jquery le digo que se haga multiselect

```
$("#SelectdestinoP").multiselect();
    $("#selectDestinatario").multiselect();
    $("#selectIpoPaquete").multiselect();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te falta agregar el atributo `multiple='multiple'`

Comment: ya se lo agregue y me lo sigue duplicando

Comment: @Alejandro.C por que no intentas realizar un ejemplo que se pueda ejecutar en el snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

No sé si lo que quieres es poder realizar una selección múltiple en el combo. Pero si es así, no lo permite el comportamiento de HTML. Otra cosa es que mediante CSS cambies cómo se muestra el componente por pantalla y simules un combo. Yo he probado el siguiente código y me funciona (es tu código **pero con el atributo multiple en el componente select como te ha indicado más arriba Yikarus**).

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectIpoPaquete" name="selectIpoPaquete" multiple="multiple">
```

No entiendo porqué no te funciona. ¿Podrías por favor concretar un poco más tu duda?.

Un saludo.

Comment: quiero que me lo pongo con el estilo de la libreria multiselec, no lo quiero como un multiselect, solo que me lo muestre con el estilo de esa libreria

Comment: No sé si te he entendido bien, perdona, ¿quieres que en vez de un combo desplegable te aparezca un cuadro de lista como en la selección múltiple?, ¿o quieres que al desplegar el combo te permita seleccionar varias opciones y no sólo una?.

Comment: quiero que sea un select normal de html, pero con el estilo del multiselect, solo eso, has decuenta el select normar de html que solo te permite seleccionar una opcion pero lo quiero con el estilo de la libreria multiselect no se si me explico, anteriormente ya lo habia hecho en otro proyecto y todo bien, pero ahora no se porque me lo duplica

Answer (score 0):

El problema que `jquery.multiselect()`, es un plugin que duplica el listado, de manera que puedas pasar de una lista a otra, es por eso por lo que te lo esta duplicando.

Para hacer lo que tu quieres, debes modificar tu jquery, de esta manera

```
$("#SelectdestinoP").attr( "multiple", "multiple" );
    $("#selectDestinatario").attr( "multiple", "multiple" );
    $("#selectIpoPaquete").attr( "multiple", "multiple" );
```